# Can not delete image file on server but other files can

Tags: php

You are right some people are really blind and dumb.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that your problem is the file permission.

You must change the file permissions of your images (0644 or 0777 in your chase).

Please read this: http://php.net/manual/en/function.chmod.php.

You can delete images in PHP using the unlink() function.

> unlink('path/to/file.jpg');

See http://php.net/manual/en/function.unlink.php .

EDIT:

ALSO you can try this:

> if(is_writable($filename))
>
> {
>
> unlink($filename)
>
> } else {
>
> echo 'At this moment this file can't be deleted';
>
> chmod(" YOUR PATH OF $filename", 0777);
>
> unlink($filename);
>
> }

AND

> if (file_exists('YOUR PATH OF $filename')) {
>
> echo 'File exist... Sorrrrrrrrrry!!!!!!!!!!!!';
>
> }

Comment: thanks for reply. Unlink not working for image files i tried it. But it works with text files.

Comment: have you tried to change files permissions of images?

Comment: If you want to verify if the file is wirtable: if(is_writable($filename)) {
  unlink($filename)
} else {
  // error handling. You can check which condition is failing here
}

Comment: I've edited my original answer, check now.

Comment: Thanks for your help. It works after changing file permission to 777